# How can I change the color of each character in a textblock

Tags: .net-4.0, wpf-controls, binding

I am writing a little diff tool and need to be able to change the color of a character depending on if its the same, added, removed.  What would be the best way to handle this?  Is a textblock a good control to start with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Run tag.

```
<TextBlock><Run Foreground="Red">T</Run>ex<Run Foreground="Green">t</Run></TextBlock>
```

Comment: How would I tie that into an datatemplate?

Comment: @Aaron that depends, I would probably use a converter of some kind and create the Runs in code, but if you provide more details in your question I'll see what I can post for you.

Comment: @Aaron or just use seperate TextBlocks